# Isometric expression of second fundamental form coefficients

Tags: differential-geometry

Apart from the function $(LN-M^2)$   composed of purely second fundamental form coefficients ( or with derivatives)  what are some other examples of such scalars which are isometrically invariant?

EDIT1:

Without  basis and as a pure guess I imagined inclusion of lesser coefficients $(g,f,c)$ in some higher invariant :) as determinant,

\begin{bmatrix}
       L & M & g\\[0.3em]
       M & N & f\\
       g & f & c
     \end{bmatrix}

or as..

\begin{bmatrix}
       L & M & E\\[0.3em]
       M & N & G\\
       E & G & F
     \end{bmatrix}

EDIT2:

i.e., if each of $(g,f,c)=1,$ whether by any chance $ (2 M - N - L)$ is also an isometric invariant?

EDIT 3:

In other words,  what qualifies $f(L,M,N)=0$ for isometric invariance?

Comment: This is a very good question.  Are you only considering the case of surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$?  In that case, I believe that (functions of) the Gauss curvature $\det(\text{II}) = LN - M^2$ is the only intrinsic isometric scalar-valued invariant derivable from the second fundamental form $\text{II}$, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: I do not know.  For a time I thought L+M may be... anyway please mention anything you consider interesting. It seemed after Gauss proved the part in Egregium thm no one entered such an ambit.

Comment: $L+N$ certainly is not. The flat plane and a rolled up toilet roll are isometric, but one is minimal and the other is not. ($L+M$ is not even invariant under local changes of coordinates.) And since the only two scalar invariants associated to a two dimensional symmetric matrix are its trace and determinant, this justify Jesse's claim.

Comment: There might be more possibilities if you allow derivatives, but the obvious ones (e.g. $|\nabla K|$) need the first fundamental form too.

Comment: @Willie Wong Yes i know, I was just imagining in line of invariants $I_1,I_2,I_3...$ when there is nothing at all.